# Element not found when following the page object style guide

Tags: javascript, protractor

As per [my previous question](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2881) I am creating this question.
I followed the guidelines in the [style guide](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/style-guide.md) but when I do exactly as I am told, the elements are not found on the page.

In my pageobject, I have defined some fields and a get-function.
When I perform the get-function, chrome is still on a blank page because it's the start of the test. Before performing the get-function, protractor seems to want to initialize the fields I have declared, thus throwing a no element found exception.

Does anybody have any experience with this?
I can't seem to get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem might come from [this part of the Style Guide](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/style-guide.md#instantiate-all-page-objects-at-the-beginning-of-the-test-suite) - if you are making any actions on the found in the page object constructor elements right there in the page object constructor - you need to put the Page Object initializations into the `beforeEach()` instead of having them directly under the `describe`:

```
var UserPropertiesPage = require('./user-properties-page');
var MenuPage = require('./menu-page');
var FooterPage = require('./footer-page');

describe('User properties page', function() {
  var userProperties,
      menu,
      footer;

  beforeEach(function () {
    userProperties = new UserPropertiesPage();
    menu = new MenuPage();
    footer = new FooterPage();
  });

  // specs
});
```

Comment: I am facing this same issue now. Tried all possibilities. But while running the text it is not even starting the suite.

Comment: would it be possible to help me on this?

Comment: My code is like i have the page objects file but the actions to be done after several test cases.

Comment: for eg: after login i have to do certain action, so those objects will be attached to the DOM after the login. When i run the suite it throws error as unable to select the element. Where no test cases started

Comment: Please help me on this. Very urgent one. Your help will be much appreciated